# Uncaught TypeError: l.renderElement is not a function

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-tooltip

I have a shared tooltip for my graph:

```
            $scope.kissaChart.setOptions({
                renderAs: 'canvas',
                drag: onDrag,
                dragEnd: onDragEnd,
                zoom: onZoom,
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0:n2}",
                    shared: true,
                    background: '#ADD8E6',
                    sharedTemplate: createTemplate
                }
            });
```

Here is my template generator :

```
function createTemplate (val1) {
    var template = "";
    if (val1 && val1.points && val1.points && val1.points.length > 0) {
        template += "<div>";

        // construct Date
        template += "Date: ";
        template += ((val1.points[0].dataItem.date) ? val1.points[0].dataItem.date : "");
        template += " " + ((val1.points[0].dataItem.actualTime) ? val1.points[0].dataItem.actualTime : "");
    }
    return template;
}
```

When I try to do mouseover a data on my series, I am shown :

```
Uncaught TypeError: l.renderElement is not a function
```

What could have been the reason?

Comment: My guess is you have wrong tooltip template. Can you include your template code? Check if it's correct, and if it is already rendered and available in function where you trying to use it.

Comment: @JarosławKończak: I have updated my question. I created a custom shared template function instead. Still, the said error occurs.

Comment: Template looks fine for me. I've checked kendo.all.min.js and jquery.min.js and I could not find renderElement function. Maybe try find it in your code? This call to renderElement has to be somewhere...

Comment: @JarosławKończak: Thanks for the help buddy. I'll try to look for it also in my code.